# What is the flaw in this proof of the Collatz Conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, collatz-conjecture

Would love any feedback for this proposed proof of the Collatz Conjecture.

(For more details explaining each step, I made a video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P0F4zbNdbTU )

Ignoring all even number (which trivially lead to an odd number), we create a "Collatz Odd-Only Variant" as such, where $n$ is a positive odd integer:

$f(n) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{n-1}{4} & \mbox{if }n\equiv 5 \mbox{ }(\mbox{mod }8)\\
\frac{3n+1}{4} & \mbox{if }n\equiv 1 \mbox{ }(\mbox{mod }8)\\ 
\frac{3n+1}{2} & \mbox{if }n\equiv 3 \mbox{ }(\mbox{mod }4)\\
\end{matrix}\right.$

This creates a tree that looks like this:

[Collatz Odd Only Variant Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qZDA.png)

We then must show that all odd numbers in this variant are connected to 1. (That is, they do not create loops or diverge elsewhere.)

To do this, we create a new simpler function, again where $n$ is a positive odd integer:

$f(n) = \left\{\begin{matrix}\
\frac{n-1}{4} & \mbox{if }n\equiv 5 \mbox{ }(\mbox{mod }8)\\
\frac{n+3}{4} & \mbox{if }n\equiv 1 \mbox{ }(\mbox{mod }8)\\ 
\frac{n-1}{2} & \mbox{if }n\equiv 3 \mbox{ }(\mbox{mod }4)\\
\end{matrix}\right.$

In this function, we *know* that all $n$'s will lead to 1, because $n$ must shrink with every iteration, and it cannot shrink below 1.

This creates a tree like this:

[Simpler Odd-Only Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq2gg.png)

Since we know this tree must contain all positive odd integers, all we have to do is disconnect and reattach some nodes so that this tree matches the "Collatz Odd-Only Variant" tree. As long as we do not reconnect a node to one of its own children (a node somewhere above it, representing the iteration of the function that preceded it), we are sure that we will never get loops and that the odd numbers will remain connected to 1.

When we disconnected the $\frac{n+3}{4}$ nodes and reattach them to $\frac{3n+1}{4}$ nodes, we know we will never connect it to a child, because we must connect it to a node that is less than $n$ (and all of $n$'s children will, by definition, be greater than $n$).

Disconnecting $\frac{n-1}{2}$ nodes to $\frac{3n+1}{2}$ is also certain to never connect to one of its own children, because iterating backwards through our function can never give us $\frac{3n+1}{2}$. (We can see this by checking the inverses of the equations in our function, even when we combine them to create composite functions.)

Since we know all nodes can be disconnected and reconnected while remaining attached to the tree connecting them all to 1, doesn't this prove the conjecture? Or what am I missing?

Would love to know your thoughts! Thank you!

Comment: Cool approach, but there are several fundamental issues with this that you handwaved over. (Mostly in the disconnect/reconnect part). I'll add an answer later detailing precise issues.

Comment: Why is $f(n)=\frac{n-1}{4}$ for $n=5$ mod $8$? I would expect $\frac{3n+1}{16}$...

Comment: Yeah, I kinda jumped over that in the explanation... In the original Collatz tree, a powers of 2 vine extends infinitely from 1, from which infinite $n$ = $5$ mod $8$ numbers branch off. And this is true for every vine (at least every vine from which odd numbers branch off at all). So instead of attaching them all to 1, we attach them to each other. It's a combination of four steps: $3n+1$, $n/2$, $n/2$, then $(n-1)/3$ (a  backwards / inverse iteration), which all simplify into one step as $(n-1)/4$. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: If you would like serious vetting of this idea, my advice is to write up an entire proof (without handwaving, with rigorous definitions). If there are any gaps, it's likely that the undertaking of composing that rigorous proof would reveal them to you.

Comment: Interesting stuff. You was clear in the video, but then I lost the track around $4n+1$ or before. I have seen these expressions before, but have not pursued them for some reason. A pdf or document describing your work in more detail I think would give us (or atleast me) a better understanding of how you're trying to prove the Collatz problem using your method.

Comment: Cool idea(+1)! Have you tried this with $n$ from the negative integers (or $3n-1$ instead of $3n+1$)? Since there are cycles there, how does this interfere with your reconnection-operation? Does it fail? does it correctly disconnect the $(-5,-7,-5,...)$ cycle from the full tree?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Definitely working to make it more rigorous, but wanted to be sure I'm not missing something... haven't tried it with negative integers, but I have tried it with the $3n-1$ variant, which fails in the "reconnection" step when $\frac{4n+1}{3} = \frac{3n-1}{2}$, which has the odd integer solution of $n = 5$, thus showing a node reconnecting to its own child, creating a loop. That said, I agree that I need to make that "reconnection" part in the proposed proof more rigorous.

Comment: At 16:25, you just gives a simple explanation saying $\frac{3n+1}{2}$ can't be in the children of $n$, but in you explanation you totally ignore the +1 or -1 term and especially in combiantions (grand-grand....grand children) where you can't just say: "it's obvious, the numerator is a power of 2 and the denominator is a power of 3" or some kind of tricky statement like that. This is all about possibility of cycles, which is unproven to this day, because if a cycle appear in your rearangement, than you will build a new tree, not connected to the known collatz tree (with cycle root "1,4,2")

Comment: The approach is far too obvious to be successful , if we consider the efforts that have been invested in this problem without a real breakthrough. Such approaches have already been studied massively and although we now know that a non-trivial cycle must be very long, the approach turned out to be unable to prove the conjecture. Moreover, we cannot rule out that the sequence diverges to $\infty$. Even if we could rule out non-trivial cycles completely, this would still have to be shown.

Comment: A good test for any putative proof of the Collatz conjecture is: Does this also work if we replace $3n+1$ with $3n+q$, where $q$ is coprime to $6$? If so, then it's not a proof, because even the $3n-1$ problem results in dynamics with three different loop attractors. If you're going to prove the conjecture, you have to somehow explain how $+1$ is different from any other choice of $q$, because all of the others have multiple loops.